# Building static library using Code::Block with MinGW

Tags: c++, mingw, codeblocks, mingw32

I am using Code::Blocks with MinGW32 on a Windows machine. And I am trying to build a static library.

[image]

I created a dummy hello world project. There is one single `main.c` file in the project. However, when I build it, I got the following message. It seems that there is no errors or warnings. It is just that no lib file is generated.

```
mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall -g  -c C:\Users\yzhong52\Desktop\hello_static_lib\main.c -o obj\Debug\main.o
cmd /c if exist bin\Debug\libhello_static_lib.a del bin\Debug\libhello_static_lib.a
mingw32-gcc-ar.exe -r -s bin\Debug\libhello_static_lib.a obj\Debug\main.o
sorry - this program has been built without plugin support
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) 0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

It says, **sorry - this program has been built without plugin support**. What does that mean? Am I missing sth?

BTW, I also tried building a dynamic library using pretty much the same method and it works fine. The *.dll and the lib*.a are generated.

**Edit:**

After switching from `mingw32-gcc-ar.exe` to `ar.exe`, everything works just fine. I still don't understand why though.

Comment: try `cd some_directory_containing_objects` `ar -rcs mylib.a *.o`  Btw.. it is never a good idea to "archive main" into your library.

Comment: Surprisingly, that works!

Comment: There is no main function in the `main.c`. That should be fine right? I didn't create this file. It was just automatically generated.

Comment: yes it is fine if there is no `main` function.