# Building 64 bit exe using mingw gcc in codeblocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks, mingw-w64

I am trying to build a 64 bit exe using minGW 64 bit. Which can be obtained from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/) (Since the project is moving from sourceforge.net to mingw-w64.org I suggest to use [mingw-w64.org](http://mingw-w64.org)). Now my machine is a 64 bit machine and when I build my code through the compiler I get back a `32` bit exe. This is the output of the program

```
-------------- Build: Debug in TestCodeBlocks (compiler: MinGW GCC - 2/17/2015)---------------

i686-w64-mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -std=c++98 -g  -c C:\Users\admin\TestCodeBlocks\main.cpp -o obj\Debug\main.o
i686-w64-mingw32-g++.exe  -o bin\Debug\TestCodeBlocks.exe obj\Debug\main.o   
Output file is bin\Debug\TestCodeBlocks.exe with size 58.17 KB
```

Any suggestions on why I might be getting back a 32 bit exe ?

This is what my toolchain in codeblocks looks like

[image]

Update:

I downloaded the 64 bit Mingw gcc compiler and this is what my settigns look like

[image]

However when I attempt to run my program I get

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -std=c++98 -g -m32  -c C:\Users\admin\TestCodeBlocks\main.cpp -o obj\Debug\main.o
ar  -o bin\Debug\TestCodeBlocks.exe obj\Debug\main.o   
ar: no operation specified
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 64bit g++ has name `x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe`.

Make sure you are using the right toolchain.

Make sure the right g++ is on `PATH` and is not hidden by another version of g++.

**UPDATE**

Use [64bit MinGW](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/4.9.2/threads-posix/seh/) version.

Also, see [Mingw-w64 Downloads](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/download.php).

Comment: `i686-` prefix means that you are using 32bit MinGW.

Comment: So after downgrading the new mingw gcc . 
When I attempt to build it I get  the message "sorry - this program has been built without plugin support"

Comment: Use `.exe` files without prefix, i.e. `g++.exe`, `ar.exe`, as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23796017/building-static-library-using-codeblock-with-mingw).

Comment: 1) `g++ -m32` will build 32bit binaries, check your project profile settings. 2) Change 'Linker for dynamic libs' to `g++`

Comment: @DmitrySokolov mingw-w64 isn't dual-target any more (i.e. you can't just use `-m32` to switch), [according to here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16304804/dual-target-mingw-w64-isnt-really-dual-target)

Comment: @Matt McNabb It only concerns to the 64bit "SEH" MinGW version that can not build 32bit binaries with SEH exception handling, but there is also "SJLJ" version which can.